# Does anyone else think Jeff sounds like Quentin Tarantino?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I'm just wondering, as from listening to the podcast over the past few months, I kept thinking, who does he sound like ?

Do you agree, or is it just me.....

Comment: Have you ever *heard* Tarantino speak?

Comment: Am already glad he doesn't sound like Daffy Duck... ;-)

Comment: ok, so just me then.....

Comment: No, but he like really does use a lot of really meaningless adverbs, and feels when he should think or conclude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's Tarantino been busy on since SO launched = nothing
What was Jeff busy with before last year = nothing (except a few blog posts)
Can Tarantino program 'C' = No
Can Jeff program 'C' = No
Have they ever been seen in the same room = No

Gentlemen we have a conspiracy.

Answer (score 7):

[Quentin Tarantino](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz4K-Rxx2Bk) vs [Jeff Atwood](http://www.vimeo.com/7355062)

I'd say no.

Comment: Hmm...Sounds pretty close to me.  Jeff even has the wavy arms.

Answer (score 3):

God I hope not because Quentin Tarantino has an *incredibly* annoying voice.

Also, he's a terrible actor. OK director but beyond bad as an actor.

Comment: I recommend you mark as "STATUS-DECLINED"

Comment: I think my own voice sounds pretty good, until I hear it from a recording.  Eeek.

Comment: @Robert: I hear the same thing when people talk about their code until someone else reviews it.

Comment: Not to mention his enormous ego.